# analogous “aerodynamics of intelligence”

Tags: sentence-structure

Does that mean that the attempt to find similarity between aerodynamics and intelligence is the ultimate goal of artificial intelligence ?
This is the text:

> An analogy is often made between AI and “artificial flight”. It is an analogy that can be usefully deployed here. At the beginning of the twentieth century there was a very limited understanding of the way in which birds and insects were able to fly: it was obvious that they did and the scientific enquiry tended to end at that point. Indeed, at the time when the Wright brothers started the aviation age (in 1903) most biology textbooks said that birds could fly “because they had the power of flight”. This is an account that owes much to Aristotle, writing in Athens in the fourth century BC. However, it is not much help to those who wish to understand how to build aircraft. As a result of the more detailed understanding of flight which stemmed from the building of successful aircraft, we now know that birds fly by complying with the laws of aerodynamics. The quest for some sort of **analogous “aerodynamics of intelligence”** is often seen as the ultimate goal of AI.
>   Just as scientific understanding of bird flight stemmed from the building of aircraft so, it is hoped, scientific understanding of intelligence will stem from attempting to build intelligent machines.

Comment: I don't think the author wanted to find any similarities between the two fields, but rather, wanted to draw parallel between the two.

Comment: *I think the author explains it rather well.

Answer (score 1):

> Aerodynamics

Is the science of how things fly (simply, I know its more about fluid dynamics). If you understand aerodynamics, you can build an airplane. The laws of aerodynamics were discovered by people who were building airplanes.

This person is saying that some kind of equivalent science *to* aerodynamics could be discovered for human thoughts, some kind of *thought-o-dynamics* if people attempt to build machines that think.

The parallel is between the process of discovery, and not meant to imply that aerodynamics has anything to do with how people think.